# How can I set the timezone in my ddev containers?

Tags: ddev

I often use `ddev ssh` (for web/nginx container) or `ddev ssh -s db` (for the db/mariadb container), and when looking at logs and such I'd like to see date/timestamps in my own timezone so I don't have to think so hard about how many hours it is from GMT. I can't use `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` in the container because the container user doesn't have root privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Configure this in the .ddev/config.yaml: `timezone: Europe/London`, for example, or `ddev config --timezone=Europe/London` This configures both the container's timezone and php's default timezone.**

See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/configuration/config/#timezone

Comment: TZ environment variable seemso to only work in PHP < 5.4.

Comment: This is really about the *container* not PHP. You may need to add php config override for that situation.

Comment: I updated to show how to set PHP default with a php override.

Answer (score 1):

As of ddev v1.8.0, you can also set the timezone in the web container by configuring .ddev/webimage-build/Dockerfile. In fact, the .ddev/webimage-build/Dockerfile.example does exactly this:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=drud/ddev-webserver:v1.8.0
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

As above, you'd also want a PHP override in `.ddev/php/tz.ini`,

```
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```