# DDEV - php has the wrong date/time inside container on Windows

Tags: php, date, ddev

I'm using DDev for local development and have one site that I set up where php thinks the date is 2.5 days previously for example currently the time/date on my host machine is:

**March 11 2020 , 4:42pm**

But when I check a page with this php:

```
<?php
$date = date('F d Y h:i:s');
echo $date;
?>
```

I see this date:
**March 09 2020 12:59**

How do I resolve this date issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 2020-03-13: [Docker Desktop 2.2.0.4 for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2204) claims to have fixed this bug.

> Fixed an issue where containers did not synchronize time with the host when the host machine wakes up from the sleep mode. Fixes docker/for-win#4526.

Original response:

Is this on Windows? Docker Desktop for Windows has been having trouble in recent releases, especially related to sleeping or hibernating the host computer. The best approach for a workaround seems to be https://thorsten-hans.com/docker-on-windows-fix-time-synchronization-issue - He recommends a PS script (or manually disable/enable time synchronization in Hyper-V admin console):

```
# fix-docker-machine-time-sync.ps1
$vm = Get-VM -Name DockerDesktopVM
$feature = "Time Synchronization"

Disable-VMIntegrationService -vm $vm -Name $feature
Enable-VMIntegrationService -vm $vm -Name $feature
```

But you can typically: `ddev poweroff` and then `ddev start`. You can also `ddev poweroff` and restart docker.

This is even in the [release notes for Docker Desktop for Windows 2.2.0.3](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2203).

> In some cases, Docker containers do not synchronize time with the host when the host machine is put to sleep

See these Docker Desktop for Windows issues:

- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5593
- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5803

And note that Docker has provided a private edge release for testing this, anybody reading this would help everything by testing it. [Link to current private edge release](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5803#issuecomment-593948334). (Remember that switching to Edge from Stable means losing all your Docker containers and volumes, which means losing ddev databases.)

Comment: ddev poweroff followed by restarting docker desktop (windows) and then ddev start all is good. Thank you.

Comment: Edited because today's Docker Desktop 2.2.0.4 release claims to fix this problem.

Answer (score -1):

try adding `date_default_timezone_set`

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
```

replace your timezone

Comment: For alternative methods, also see [How can I set the timezone in my ddev containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255466/how-can-i-set-the-timezone-in-my-ddev-containers)

Comment: This issue seems to be having the entirely wrong date, not having wrong timezone. In ddev you set the timezone with `timezone: <sometimezone>` in the .ddev/config.yaml, but it doesn't sound like that will help this user.

Comment: I have added that and no change - also this is only happening on my laptop, not desktop. Looks like there might be something specific to my laptop that is causing it but I have no idea.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why should that help?