# How can I use the Europe/Kyiv timezone in DDEV?

Tags: ddev

I work with Drupal ^10 on ddev. Previously about year or so I faced issue, after some update, keeps throwing error. Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Europe/Kyiv' is invalid in Drupal\system\TimeZoneResolver->setDefaultTimeZone() (line 54 of core/modules/system/src/TimeZoneResolver.php).

When i tried ddev config --timezone=Europe/Kyiv I got next error Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): Invalid date.timezone value 'Europe/Kyiv', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now. in Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatter->format() (line 105 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Datetime/DateFormatter.php). Before that update everything was fine, and no errors with timezone. So if I understand correctly, there was some update with tzdata and timezone was changed to more correct version instead of Europe/Kiev => Europe/Kyiv, that was included in some ubuntu version, but ddev building images like before that update. Maybe someone configured ddev to fix such problem.

Comment: [How can I set the timezone in my ddev containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255466/how-can-i-set-the-timezone-in-my-ddev-containers) Can the answer here help you solve it?

Comment: Hi Martin, unfortunately, no. I used following commands:
ddev config --webimage-extra-packages=tzdata --dbimage-extra-packages=tzdata
ddev config --timezone=Europe/Kyiv
ddev restart
 and on the ddev start step I' getting following error:
#11 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-myproject-built 3/3] RUN apt-get -qq update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests tzdata
And there is more info in error, but limitation of the comment won't allow to show it full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the Debian `tzdata` package has recently changed to use `Europe/Kyiv` instead of `Europe/Kiev`.

You can:

1. Use `Europe/Kiev` for now or
2. Add the `tzdata` package to get it updated with

```
ddev config --webimage-extra-packages=tzdata --dbimage-extra-packages=tzdata
ddev config --timezone=Europe/Kyiv
ddev restart
```

In the v1.23.0 release of DDEV it will be Europe/Kyiv by default (since it will pick up the latest `tzdata`).

Comment: Greetings @rfay, I tried solution №2 but on ddev restart I keep getting error:
 and on the ddev start step I' getting following error:

Comment: #11 [drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-myproject-built 3/3] RUN apt-get -qq update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests tzdata
#11 7.931 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
(Reading database ... 13056 files and directories currently installed.)
#11 8.103 Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2024a-0ubuntu0.20.04_all.deb ...
#11 8.109 Unpacking tzdata (2024a-0ubuntu0.20.04) over (2022g-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
#11 CANCELED

Comment: There is more in error body, but I don't wish to create wall of comments with errors from console log.

Comment: Maybe this is also important part of an error so I will include it:
#11 [drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5-myproject-built 3/8] RUN apt-get -qq update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qq install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests tzdata xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base

Comment: You have a variety of problems, it would be easier to help you in DDEV Discord, https://discord.gg/5wjP76mBJD - 1) the `drud` org was retired a year ago. 2) DDEV v1.21.5 is really, really old. Please use current v1.22.7, which solves a certificate problem. 3) Consider trying it without the `--dbimage-extra-packages=tzdata` flag.   DDEV installation instructions are at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/install/ddev-installation/

Comment: Thank you @rfay, I updated my ddev to v1.22.7 and run Add the tzdata package to get it updated with commands described in step 2 of your original response and all fixed.